# Maintain different directory structure in different git branches

Tags: git

I had a problem with git. I have a repository of a project that's getting old and want to start a new version. I've created a new branch (`3.0-wip`) and deleted the files and folders to start again. However, if I checkout my master branch, the files and folders are gone from there too.

How can I have my repository so my master branch has everything the remote repo has, but a completely different working directory in my `3.0-wip` that I can modify to my heart's content without destroying the files and folders in any other branch?

Comment: Did you commit to your 3.0-wip branch before checking out to your master branch? If not, that's probably the problem.

Comment: I cloned external repo. Created and checked out new `3.0-wip` branch. Deleted files/folders via Finder. Created new `index.php` file and committed it. If I checkout my `master` branch then the files are still gone, and `git status` shows all files/folders as 'deleted:'.

Comment: Did you git add . | git add -u before your commit ? How did you commit those changes in your 3.0-wip branch ?

Comment: well.. this question title is of interest to what I'm doing, but what you're describing isn't 'maintaining' differences in directory structures between remote git repos (in respect to branches or otherwise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Commited* changes in one branch do not affect another branch. You need to commit all the deletes as well, that's what Dominic tried to explain. Simply do:

```
$ git co $NEWBRANCH
$ git status
```

And you will see zillions of uncommited deletes. You have to use `git rm` to remove files.
Not sure `git add --all` will handle deletes as well. Anyway, this is IMO not the best way to start anew as the new branch will still have the old history.

I think it is better to create a new "disconected" commit:

1. Create a new repo: `mkdir $DIR; cd $DIR; git init`
2. Create the initial commit. `touch README; git add --all; git commit -m "Init"`

Now go to to original repo and:

1. Add it as a remote: `git remote add start-anew $DIR/.git`
2. fetch it: `git fetch start-anew`
3. pull it in: `git co -b start-anew start-anew/master`

And voila a branch with fresh empty history.

You may want to delete the remote then, and also change the remote for the branch. I am usually editing `.git/config` manually, so far without an accident.

Comment: Tried to follow this, but when I tried to fetch the `start-anew` repository, I get a 'fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly' error.

Comment: Works for me with `git version 1.7.6.4`?

Comment: It worked for me by pushing the `start-anew` repository to Github, and then fetching from there. Must be something to do with trying to fetch from my local machine.

Answer (score 8):

What's happening is you're not using git correctly.  There's absolutely no problem with creating a branch and deleting files and folders.  When you switch back to your master branch, the deleted files and folders will be restored, as they haven't been deleted from that branch.

What's happening in your case is that you've removed the file/folders out from under git, by using the operating system delete, rather than the "git rm" command.   That's why git status reports them as "deleted".  It's also why the files stay deleted when you switch branches.  git is expecting the files to be there and they're not.

Git status tells you to run "git add" but that doesn't work.  Since the file is no longer there, running git add will fail silently.  You might not notice but the message also tells you to run "git rm".  You may think you can't do that since the file is gone, but that's not true.  The rm command will still succeed in removing the file from the repo, even though you've already removed it from the file system.

The other, and easier thing you can do is run git add -A.  The -A flag will tell add to notice any deleted or added files.

Try this for a test:

```
git init test-delete
cd test-delete
touch filea
mkdir dir_b
touch dir_b/fileb
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b new_branch
rm -rf dir_b
git add -A
git commit -m "deleted files from branch"
(ls to prove files arent' there)
git checkout master
(ls to show files have been restored)
git checkout new_branch
(ls to show files are gone again)
```