# How do I have separate files for development branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'm new to git and version control, and had a quick question. I have a project with two branches, `master` and `development`. I want to have different files in my `development` branch, than the ones in my `master` branch. Is this possible, and if so, how can I set this up? By the way, I'm under the impression that branches are basically folders, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks much!

Comment: start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748272/introduction-to-git-and-practical-usage-patterns

Comment: "*I want to have different files in my development branch, than the ones in my master branch. Is this possible, and if so, how can I set this up?*" What do you mean, can you please give more explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain different directory structure in different git branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540080/maintain-different-directory-structure-in-different-git-branches)

Comment: By the way, **no**, branches ***are not basically folders***. You're thinking too much of SVN or TFS, which Git only very *superficially* resembles. Branches in Git are basically labels that you attach to lines of development (commits). You can think of Git as just representing a tree of commits, where Post-it notes (branches) are attached to different branches, as a sort of "bookmark".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a very simple and interesting tool.
I would suggest to follow below process:

1. First of all, go to your git repo and check you are in which branch by using "**git branch**". It will give output you something like this:

   ***master**
2. Then use command **git branch branch-name**, it will create a branch. If you want to see the branch run "git branch" command again, it will now be visible to you something like this:

   ***master**

   **branch-name**

   Here "*" denotes your current branch.
3. Now since you have created new branch you can switch to your new branch and start working on it. For switching your branch, just type command **"git checkout branch-name"**. And to verify again, which is your current branch, run "git branch" and you will be amazed the "*" will now move to your new branch.

Make your changes, commit them, push them and again switch back to master using same checkout command.

One more important point is that make sure that your changes should be commited (tracked) before switching to branch, otherwise it will popup error of untracked changes.

You can also create and switch to new branch by **"git checkout -b branch-name"** in one step also. I broked that command in order to make you understand easily.

I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created both branches, you can switch between them by using the

```
git checkout [name of branch]
```

command. So let's say you've got a master branch with some files in it that you've committed. Then you can checkout to a development branch, and create another file.

If you checkout from development to master and back, you'll see the files in your folder actually change to reflect whatever branch you're on.

So a branch isn't exactly a folder itself, it's more like a state of a folder and you can switch states using checkout.

I highly recommend playing around with git, there are some [really good free tutorials](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) out there now.

Comment: If you haven't created the other branch yet, use `git checkout -b [branch name]`